# How to generalize C from A and B.

Tags: matrices, contest-math, numerical-linear-algebra

I have Two matrix $A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
 a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
 a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $B=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text b_{11} & b_{12}  \\
 b_{21} & b_{22}  \\
 \end{array}
\right)$. 
 Some operation (say *) gives matrix $C$ such that 
 $A*B=C=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text a_{11}+B & a_{12}+B& a_{13}+B\\
 a_{21}+B & a_{22}+B & a_{23}+B\\
a_{31}+B & a_{32}+B & a_{33}+B\\
 \end{array}
\right)$. Is there any way to generalize C from A and B something like Kronecker Product/sum?.  Is there any regular name of this operation?

Comment: How do you add a scalar to a matrix?  That is, what does $a_{11} + B$ mean if $a_{11} = 2$ and $B = \pmatrix{1&2\\0&3}$?

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with contest math?

Comment: If $a_{11} + B = a_{11}I + B$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix), then you can write
$$
A*B = A \otimes I_2 + I_3 \otimes B
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Are you sure with the $I_3 \otimes B$ part? Wouldn't this produce a matrix with $B$-blocks on the diagonal and $0$-blocks everywhere else?

Comment: @Roland whoops! Good catch

Answer (score 1):

Recall the Kroneker product, which produces a large block matrix  from two matrices $S$ and $T$ where the numbers of block columns and rows $S \otimes T$ are the same as the number of columns and rows of $S$ and the $(i,j)-$th block is the matrix $s_{ij}T$.

If the blocks $a_{ij}+B$ in the resulting matrix are read as $a_{ij}I + B$, we can write your desired matrix as the sum of two block matrices: One which contains blocks of the form $a_{ij}I$, and one matrix where every block is of the form $1B$.

Thus, we can write $$C = A \otimes I + E \otimes B,$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix corresponding to the size of $B$ (i.e. $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$ in your example), and $E$ is the matrix filled with ones, corresponding to the size of $A$ (i.e. $\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1 \end{pmatrix}$ in your example).